# Scrolling not working in mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile

For some reason the website I'm building will not allow a user to scroll down when viewed in mobile Safari.

The link to the site is here:
http://javinladish.com/instapoker.html

Can anybody understand why this is happening?

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps out.

Another update:
When I view the site on Google Chrome for iOS, and do "Request Desktop Site", everything loads fine and scrolling works flawlessly. So I'm guessing the inability to scroll has to do with something automatically applied for the mobile site.

Comment: Please post code and what you have tried so far to solve this problem. Posting an external link and expecting folks to debug it for you doesn't help here.

Comment: @beautifulcoder The website contains quite a bit of code and possibilities for this bug occurrence. I thought the best way to go about it would be for people to see the bug in action, rather than dumping the entire lot of code here. Perhaps this has happened to someone before and they can shed light on what they did to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up having to do with the plugin Skrollr causing problems with the mobile site.

Answer (score 0):

Try overflow:scroll on body element.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Grr, this is such a weird bug.